# HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest() return null?

Tags: gwt

I want to get a Attribute of session in GWT app.  i get Session like this

```java
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
System.out.println("Check HttpServletRequest");       
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

but `this.getThreadLocalRequest()` is always `null`.

CODE :

Client:

```java
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("service.s3gwt")
public interface getAttributeSession extends RemoteService 
{
    String getSessionAttribute(String name);
}

public interface getAttributeSessionAsync 
{
    void getSessionAttribute(String name, AsyncCallback<String> callback);
}
```

Server:

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import daTotNghiep.client.service.getAttributeSession;

public class getAttributeSessionImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements getAttributeSession 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getSessionAttribute(String name) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
    System.out.println("Check HttpServletRequest");
    if(request == null) System.out.println("SO BAD");

   //   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   // System.out.println("ID session "+session.getId());

     return "";
    }
}
```

When call method `getSessionAttribute()` I see that `this.getThreadLocalRequest()` always returns `null`. So Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getThreadLocalRequest()` is implemented in the class `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet`, which is inherited by `RemoteServiceServlet`. The implementation sets the field `perThreadRequest` (which is used by `getThreadLocalRequest()`) only for the method `doPost()`. That means, `getThreadLocalRequest()` will only return the request if it is called from within a POST request, and then only if you didn't overwrite `doPost()` without calling the super method.

So to make sure `getThreadLocalRequest()` doesn't return `null`

- make sure you're calling itfrom within a POST request (and not a GET or some other HTTP request type).
- make sure you didn't overwrite `doPost()` without calling `super.doPost()`

Comment: I was just digging around this and wanna point out that `doPost()` is final in `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet`. So it couldn't be overriden.